# Why does "some" line have higher delay that "full" one due to memory pressure?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory, cgroups, sysfs

I have the following stats:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/memory.pressure 
some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=1954777
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=1626895
```

The documentation states:

> The “some” line indicates the share of time (*total*) in which at least some tasks are stalled on a given resource.

> The “full” line indicates the share of time in which all non-idle tasks are stalled on a given resource simultaneously.

Source: [PSI - Pressure Stall Information — The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html)

Why does "full" line have a total lower than "some" line? What am I missing?

Comment: 'Some' is a more inclusive classification than 'all'. As Abraham Lincoln once said: "You can stall all of the tasks some of the time, and you can stall some of the tasks all of the time, but you can't stall all of the tasks all of the time".

Comment: Let me see if I understood, "full" means all of the tasks stalled at once, doesn't it?

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation (supposing you have 20 tasks) is: During the critical times when all 20 tasks were stalled, 1626895 ticks were marked. During the times when 1 to 19 tasks were stalled (but at least one was not), 1954777 ticks were marked. One might assume "full" implies some external resource problem, and "some" merely that the tasks were queuing among themselves, but I know sweet nothing about this area.